# Some program itself starts and stops in a fraction of seconds.. whats that

Tags: windows-7, virus, spyware

Some program itself starts and stops in a fraction of seconds..

Yes and it happens so quickly that i am never able to see the name or even the icon of the program..

it is visible only in the taskbar, no window is visible..

It happens almost every 5 minutes on my machine..

i am not able to figure out whats that..

I tried utilizing camstudio to capture a video of the  taskbar portion but camstudio is making some titled videos and the icon is not clearly visible ..

please help..

Comment: Define “some program”. Is it a specific one?

Comment: no.. well i don't know.. its something unknown..

Comment: You don’t know *which* program(s) close? `o.O`

Comment: well.. you didn't understand question.. its an action that takes so quickly that a human can't judge which program executed..

Comment: Oh okay. I thought you meant that sometimes when you run a program, it closes quickly instead of staying open. Instead, you are saying that a program launches on its own right? Then as Mark suggested, try running ProcessMonitor to see what program is run. Alternately, you *should* be able to use Camstudio to capture the screen; just set the frame-rate to the highest setting and the codec to uncompressed or Microsoft Video 1 (i.e., something that is very fast).

Comment: well.. now i've trying something like that, lets see what do i get in the end.. initially i got an online update thing used by a internet dongle.. removing which seams like things resolved but i won't decide so easily..

Comment: *> initially i got an online update thing used by a internet dongle*   Yes, it could be a program for some hardware. Sadly, I have seen many devices (printers, cameras, etc.) that like to install a *lot* of junk programs that can run and flash and crash, etc. `:-(` Use a program like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) or [MSConfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) to see what programs are being run. Then you can disable/enable some to see which one is being bad.

Answer (score 3):

Get ProcessMonitor from SysInternals (It's free) and start it recording for 5-10 minutes, stopping it right after you see the program appear and then vanish. It'll have recorded any registry key or file access made, and maybe you can figure it out that way.

Or, open a command prompt and run tasklist, spamming it over and over until you see the program show up - if you run tasklist at just the right time, you'll see the name of the executable.

Oh - another thing that might give a clue is AutoRuns from SysInternals, see what is being started when your PC boots Windows, and see if there's anything there that you are suspicious of. Naturally, you must be careful with these tools not to disable something that you really needed, etc. (Seriously, get someone to help you.)

Comment: This thing really helps.. am sure, i get to the roots of what ever comes my way..

Comment: @HariOm Best of luck!